# Chilkat - Duplicate attachment

Tags: email, attachment, chilkat

I've an EML file with ONE attachment, but when I load it with the Chilkat email component, the values for numOfAttachments AND NumRelatedItems are both 1.
The attachment is a PDF file.

Why is the PDF file also a related item? How can I ensure, that the PDF file will be only processed one time.

Example:

```
var email = new Chilkat.Email();
email.LoadEml("myEmlFile.eml");

for (int i = 0; i < email.NumAttachments; i++) {
 // ... do something
}

for (int i = 0; i < email.NumRelatedItems; i++) {
 // ... do something
}
```

Thanks

Best regards
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, it is possible that an item is both a related item and an attachment.  The semantics of it can point both ways.  Examine the .eml in a text editor to see what you have.  Where is the PDF located in the nested MIME structure?  If, for example, it was directly under the multipart/mixed MIME part, then it would certainly be only an attachment.  If, however, the PDF was located under the multipart/related, then it would be a related item -- especially if the content-disposition is inline.  But most people expect the PDF to be an attachment.

In other words, the email may be such that the PDF is located under multipart/related with an "inline" disposition, but some programmers expect it to be a related item, whereas others expect it to be an attachment.  There's no single solution for everybody..